# Embedded Nativescript Angular code into existing iOS project, Angular 7 throws Error: Error: A Frame must be used to navigate to a Page

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular7, nativescript-angular

When i run iOS xcode project with embedded nativescript frameworks and nativescript code, apps gives error when try to show/load nativescript pages into xcode console:
**Error: Error: A Frame must be used to navigate to a Page.**

Below are the my Objective-c Function which starts loading NativeScript pages.

```
- (NSString*) scriptStringToLoad {
    NSString *source = @"var platform_1 = require('nativescript-angular/platform');"
    "var app_module_1 = require('./app/app.module');"
    "var platform = platform_1.platformNativeScriptDynamic();"
    "platform.bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);";

    return  source;
}
```

Below is NativeSctipt part:

> 1. app.module.ts file code

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. app.component.ts file code

   import { Component } from "@angular/core";

   @Component({
       moduleId: module.id,
       selector: "ns-app",
       templateUrl: "app.component.html"
   })
   export class AppComponent {

   ```
   onButtonTap() {
       console.log('Hi hello button tapped');
   }
   ```

   }
3. app.component.html file code

Comment: What you have inside `app.component.html`?

Comment: My app.component.html has below code

 <StackLayout > 
    <Button text="Button" (tap)="onButtonTap()"></Button>
    <Label class ="backgroundColor" text="Welocme Home"></Label>
    
    </StackLayout>

Comment: Your app.component.html should only have  <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet> and to build you can use tns build  with --bundle flag to enable webpack build and check. You can follow the structure as in this playground sample - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=iayuat

Answer (score 0):

Your app.component.html should only have

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

and to build you can use tns build with --bundle flag to enable webpack build and check.

You can follow the structure as in this playground sample - play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=iayuat

Comment: My requirement is to push or present Nativescript page into existing iOS project, not to completely make nativescript as starting point for my existing iOS app. I am trying to run into XCode project which has all nativescript framework embedded. <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet> is only if you want to use router approach but till now i don't want to route anywhere. just want to show nativescript page i.e "app.component.html" into existing iOS app.

Comment: Ok got it, You can refer to this - https://www.nativescript.org/blog/embedding-nativescript-in-an-existing-ios-app , but as per NativeScript it is still an experimental approach. Not sure if it completely supported.